# Changing application's main window GUI layout to be in code

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

In my application the main window's GUI is designed in the Qt-Creator designer.  I have had some trouble in getting it to look just the way I'd like, but I can when doing the GUI in C++ code.

So, I plan to change the application's main window to be laid out in code.

What should I keep in mind when doing this?

How do I make sure all the menu items and button clicks etc. get migrated, too?

Answer (score 1):

In my Qt experience I almost always write layout in code and here is what I can suggest:

a) Spend some time thinking which Layout to use, personally I tend to use either QGridLayout or nested QHboxLayout and QVBoxLayout which give you lot of flexibility.

b) I normally declare all child widgets as class variables always pointers and I create the real objects in the Main windows constructor.

About not to forget any control I suggest to print the XML of the UI file and draw a line on each control you recreate in the code.

Answer (score 1):

As a good starting point, simply copy-pase the `setupUi` method from the `ui_xxx.h` file that uic had generated for you. You can then manually edit the setup code to suit your needs.